# VBA Excel show the result of a combo box in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I want to show the value of a combo box in a cell. When I select a combo box, the value of it should be shown in a cell.
My code doesn't work:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    With Sheet3.ComboBox1
        .Clear
        For Each Cell In Range("A1:A15")
           .AddItem Cell.Value
        Next
    End With

    index = ComboBox1.Value
    Set car = Cells(1, 4)
    Cells(1, 4).Value = index
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
.Clear
```

And try to be explicit like this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    'you don't need a loop to add values, use List property
    Me.ComboBox1.List = Application.Transpose(Sheet3.Range("A1:A15"))
    'if you want the data transferred to the sheet that contains the ComboBox, use below
    Me.Range("D1") = Me.ComboBox1.Value
    'if not, use below the commented line
    'Sheet3.Range("D1") = Me.ComboBox1.Value
End Sub
```

Now the only problem is, how you would initialize the values.
At first, your `ComboBox1` list will be empty.
You can try to use another event to do that. HTH.